# Dynamical System in Polar Coordinates

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I have a dynamical system defined by :

$ \dot x = {(x+iy)^n + (x-iy)^n \over2}$ and  $\dot y = {(x+iy)^n - (x-iy)^n \over2i}$

Converting the system to polar coordinates gives the system:

$\dot r = r^ncos((n-1)\theta)$ and $ \dot \theta = r^{n-1} sin ((n-1)\theta)$

Now the problem I have is finding an equation for the trajectory of the system that passes through the point (x,y) = (0,-1) given n =4.

Computing $ \dot x $ and $\dot y $ at the point (0,-1) gives 0 and -i respectively.  This shows that the there is no x motion for the system at (0,-1).  How do I begin to find the equation for the trajectory?  My thoughts are to use $\dot r$ and solve for it explicitly but I can not make the differential equation $\dot r = r^ncos((n-1)\theta)$ separable.

Comment: could you solve for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ using $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\frac{\dot{r}}{\dot{\theta}}$?

Comment: Good idea, I will post my attempt

Comment: Using complex numbers $z=x+iy$, one gets $\dot z=z^n$ hence, for every $n\ne-1$, $$\frac1{z(0)^{n-1}}-\frac1{z(t)^{n-1}}=3t.$$ If $z(0)=-i$ and $n=4$, $$z(t)^3=\frac{-1}{3t+i}=\frac{-3t+i}{9t^2+1}.$$ In polar coordinates $x+iy=re^{i\theta}$, this reads $$r(t)=\frac1{\sqrt[6]{9t^2+1}}\qquad 3\theta(t)=\arg(-3t+i).$$

Comment: Typo: $3t$ should read $(n-1)t$. (Of course, one line later, one assumes that $n=4$ hence the rest works.)

Answer (score 1):

Attempt

$ dr \over d\theta$ = $ \dot r \over \dot \theta$ = $rcot(3\theta)$

Now the differential equation is separable and after solving gives:

$ r = C (sin(3\theta))^{1/3}$

Using relation $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ and $tan^{-1}(y/x)$ gives r = 1  and $ \theta = -pi/4$ This yields a C = -1.122